# How to deserialize kafka message with c#

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, debezium

I have succesfully implemented a debezium postgres connector in Kafka, that is intercepting changes made in my posgres table.

I have also succesfully implemented a consumer, that is subscribing my topic.

However I want to deserialize my kafka message:

My message looks like this:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "member_id"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "first_name"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "last_name"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "name": "io.debezium.time.MicroTimestamp",
                        "version": 1,
                        "field": "created_date"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "name": "dbserver01.membership.member.Value",
                "field": "before"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "int32",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "member_id"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "first_name"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "last_name"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "name": "io.debezium.time.MicroTimestamp",
                        "version": 1,
                        "field": "created_date"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "name": "dbserver01.membership.member.Value",
                "field": "after"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "version"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "connector"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "name"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "ts_ms"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "name": "io.debezium.data.Enum",
                        "version": 1,
                        "parameters": {
                            "allowed": "true,last,false,incremental"
                        },
                        "default": "false",
                        "field": "snapshot"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "db"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "sequence"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "schema"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "table"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "txId"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "lsn"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": true,
                        "field": "xmin"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": false,
                "name": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source",
                "field": "source"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": false,
                "field": "op"
            },
            {
                "type": "int64",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "ts_ms"
            },
            {
                "type": "struct",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "type": "string",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "id"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "total_order"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "int64",
                        "optional": false,
                        "field": "data_collection_order"
                    }
                ],
                "optional": true,
                "field": "transaction"
            }
        ],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "dbserver01.membership.member.Envelope"
    },
    "payload": {
        "before": null,
        "after": {
            "member_id": 1004,
            "first_name": "Paula",
            "last_name": "Abdul",
            "created_date": 1705881600000000
        },
        "source": {
            "version": "1.9.7.Final",
            "connector": "postgresql",
            "name": "dbserver01",
            "ts_ms": 1705952843423,
            "snapshot": "false",
            "db": "postgres",
            "sequence": "[\"37097688\",\"37098080\"]",
            "schema": "membership",
            "table": "member",
            "txId": 771,
            "lsn": 37098080,
            "xmin": null
        },
        "op": "c",
        "ts_ms": 1705952843807,
        "transaction": null
    }
}
```

Now essentially I want to deserialize my payload including the "op": "c" which tells me whether to create, update or delete my data (in this case create).

I am sure there is a standard way of processing my message, but I cannot find any example how to process my message data.

I have created a member class in my consumer console app, but I am not sure how to deserialize my kafka message correctly.

I have read to use a schema registry, but I am not sure how to proceed with that option.

I have tried looking at this example:
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/JsonSerialization/Program.cs

But my console app simply crashes with an error when running it.
The program [27728] has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: The example is using Newtonsoft.json a pretty common package. You can probably also use System.Text.Json. Here's an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how- You will have to make objects for each object in your json

Comment: @hallibut - My comments on a previous answer have gone missing, since the answer has been deleted.
I know  about serialization and deserialization and worked with it numerously with xml, binary, bson and json. 
I am looking for a more kafka way of deserializing the kafka message. You can see the link in my question. I tried that approach but my app keeps exiting with a thread error.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that I need make use of schema registry. I want to try doing it not using confluent. I just need to find an example, if anyone can help me here, I will most grateful.